# How to handle different versions of a Firefox Addon in different Firefox versions

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, store, compatibility, versioning

I've programmed an addon for Firefox. In the "backend view" of the Firefox addon store I now see the message, that my addon is no longer compatible to Firefox starting from version 30.0 (see screenshot1).

A quick look into the new API told me what to change and so I did.

But how can I make shure, that useres with a Firefox 29.0 or older will still get the "old" version of the addon, and users surfing on Firefox 30.0 and newer get my updated addon?

Does the shop backend makes that choice? Because when uploading new addons I can set the supported versions of Firefox (see screenshot2).

And how to increase the addons id? Now it is set to 1.0.0. Should I go with 1.0.1 or should I leave some "space" for updates to the "old" version and start with 2.0.0?

I'm confused. Could anybody please help me? Thanks in advance!

Bye
Niels

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: You misspell "Nils" ;p

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't the AMO support site. Better suited places would be [the AMO forums](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/), the AMO editors mailing list `amo-editors@mozilla.org` or the `#amo` and/or `#addons` IRC channels on `irc.mozilla.org`.

Comment: What was the code that you had to fix to make it compatible for future versions? For example in my addon "ntHotkey" an id of an element on the new tab page changed. So I went `if (oldId) { } else { //use new id }`. Don't make and support multiple parallel versions. Unless its drastically different and you have to as last resrot. Just make one version that checks and uses the appropriate code. No need to do anything on the AMO/store backend. Just tell people that your old version won't work in FF30+.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! So, one code basis with if-else-statements against the browser versions is the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes these incompatibility notices are false alarms ([this seems especially the case with version 30](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/05/27/compatibility-for-firefox-30/)) and sometimes the resolve spontaneously because Mozilla runs batch tests or the like.  If the compatibility issue is with (say) widgets vs. ActionButtons, there are ways to accommodate both levels of FF version support with `try`...`catch` structures.

Comment: Hey, it actually is widget vs. ActionButton. How did you now? :). So, `var widget; try {widget = require('sdk/widget');} catch() {widget = require('sdk/ui')}` (in pseudo code, I don't know the exact require statements by heart) would do the trick?

Comment: I'd do the `try` on the `ActionButton` API, unless the preference is for widgets, in which case the `catch` kicks in in some possible future FF version in which `widget` support will actually be discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

This is what an AMO developer answered via mail:

> AMO should offer the right version depending on the browser version
>   you're using. In the worst case, users can click on the All Versions
>   link and see past versions that can be installed.

So I uploaded my updated extension and set the browser-compatibility to Firefox 30.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can include separate code for different FF versions if you want [Chrome registration - appversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#appversion)

Here is an example from **GreaseMonkey** `chrome.manifest`:

```
overlay    chrome://browser/content/scratchpad.xul chrome://greasemonkey/content/scratchpad-overlay.xul appversion<23.0
overlay    chrome://browser/content/devtools/scratchpad.xul chrome://greasemonkey/content/scratchpad-overlay.xul appversion>=23.0
```